# Sharp-symbol offset and text left-justification problem with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to improve a figure that I made with the tikz package. It currently looks like this:

### [image: figure]

Specifically, I have the following two questions regarding the row and column headers:

- The sharp symbol "\sharp" seems to offset the preceding letters vertically. How do I prevent this?
- How do I left-justify the row headers?

I have no idea how to do these things, even after searching. Any help would be appreciated. This is the code snippet that produces the headings:

```
\foreach \x/\y in { 1/C,
                    2/C$\sharp$,
                    3/D,
                    4/E$\flat$,
                    5/E,
                    6/F,
                    7/F$\sharp$,
                    8/G,
                    9/A$\flat$,
                    10/A,
                    11/B$\flat$,
                    12/B}
{
    \draw (\x,13) node{\y};
    \draw (0,13-\x) node{\y};
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `\smash{$\sharp$}`, etc. to make LaTeX think it has no height.  To left justify rowheaders, I would use `\makebox[width][l]{header}` where width is chosen at some appropriate value, the widest width you will encounter.  Providing us a full MWE would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixing the vertical alignment, you can set `node [text depth=0pt]`. This tells TikZ to ignore the descenders of the text for the alignment.

For left-justifying the row headings, you can set `node [anchor=west]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in { 1/C,
                    2/C$\sharp$,
                    3/D,
                    4/E$\flat$,
                    5/E,
                    6/F,
                    7/F$\sharp$,
                    8/G,
                    9/A$\flat$,
                    10/A,
                    11/B$\flat$,
                    12/B}
{
    \draw (\x,13) node [text depth=0pt] {\y};
    \draw (-0.5,13-\x) node [anchor=west] {\y};
}
\draw [shift={(-0.5,-0.5)}] (1,1) grid (13,13);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```